# subfigure error

Tags: subfloats

I'm having a problem putting a `subfigure` in my document. The code is as follows:

```
    \begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[scale=.45]{A+} 
      \caption{A}
      \label{fig:A} 
     \end{subfigure}

     \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[scale=.45]{B+} 
      \caption{B}
      \label{fig:B} 
    \end{subfigure}     
   \end{figure}
```

The error is as follows:

```
Error: Package caption Error: up undefined. \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
```

Can anybody help me?
First, I want to put one image on top of another and I use the package:

```
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{subcaption}
```

Comment: Use  `textfont={it,up}` in the option for caption.

Comment: Have you tried  `={it,up} `, it and up are not general options on their own. Otherwise check the caption manual. Btw next time please post a full minimal example instead of sniplets like this. Then it is a lot easier for others to help. Btw isn't up the default anyways and it,up makes no sense

Comment: I use: `\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the received suggestions, you have to group `{bf,up}` in your code, modified code given below:

```
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={it,up}]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont={bf,up},textfont={it,up}]{subcaption}
```

Comment: Credits should goes to @Bernard...